# How to retrieve text only from wp_content() not from wp_excerpt()?

Tags: posts, text

I'm currently developing a website with WordPress 3.5 and I need to retrieve **Post Text (Only text, not include images)** at **Archive Page**. I can retrieve it with `wp_excerpt()` method without any problems. But the main problem for me is that I can't get the exact text layout. `wp_excerpt()` method returns text which ignores all extra spaces and line breaks. What should I do? I think I will get **Only Post Text with Exact Layout** if I can retrieve from `wp_content()` method. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Or even simpler:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );
```

By using:

- [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)

> Retrieve the post content. (Must be used in a Loop)
>
> An important difference from `the_content()` is that `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the '`the_content`'. This means that `get_the_content()` will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things.

- [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/)

> Properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.

Comment: This should be approved as the answer.

Comment: It's also does not cover shortcodes, wrap it into ```strip_shortcodes()```

Answer (score 4):

There's not a native WordPress function to retrieve text only, but you can use WordPress filters and regex code to target this specific problem.

To get unformated text, use [get_the_content() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content). To apply all filters, use it this way( see codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage ):

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

Before applying filters, there is a space for you custom modifications, e.g. removing images. This way:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', "", $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

Source of preg_replace code: http://www.phpzag.com/php-remove-image-tags-from-a-html-string-with-preg_replace/

You may need to remove also shortcodes, if any are used. This can be done also via preg_replace and I bet you'll find some on the google.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and also apologize for my late response. I tried like this. `$content = get_the_content(); $content = preg_replace('/(<)([gallery])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', ”, $content); $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); echo $content;` But it didn't work. No images are removed and can't see any text that I expect.

Answer (score 2):

I combined results from the other answers on this post to strip images and audio etc, but keeping the formatting. By first getting the content with `get_the_content`, then passing it through the "the_content" filter to add formatting etc, and then using php's`strip_tags` to only allow a limited number of tags.

`strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()),"<p><a><br><b><u><i><strong><span><div>");`

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly for me. Just add this to your `functions.php` file in your theme:

```
// Hook : to get content without images
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_get_content_without_images');

function wpse_get_content_without_images() {
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = preg_replace( '/<img[^>]+./', '', $content );
    echo $content;
}
```

Then, get your post content the standard way using `echo the_content();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to remove gallery content and to have only content.

```
$content = get_the_content();
        $content = preg_replace('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', "", $content);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
        echo $content;
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what some of the other answers have said only with less explanation?