# How to remove images from showing in a post with the_content()?

Tags: posts, images, attachments, text

Trying to learn more about creating my own themes and not using any plugins I wanted an ability to display all the images in a post excluding the thumbnail in my `single-foobar.php` file and I can do that with:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

$thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'exclude' => $thumb_ID
  );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
 if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
       echo '<div class="portproject">';
       $image_res = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, ' img-responsive' );
       echo $image_res;
       echo '</div>';
      }
 }
 else { ?>
    <span> No pictures loaded at this time</span>
 <?php } endwhile; endif; ?>
```

However, when I apply my static HTML and then try to call `get_the_content()` with:

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

it removes the images but leaves a `(image)` in the post with spaces then displays the remaining text. I did find a similar [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87909/how-to-retrieve-text-only-from-wp-content-not-from-wp-excerpt) but it suggests using `get_the_content()` but that strips all the styling from the post.  So my question is how can I strip images from `the_content()`?  I did find "[Getting the_content WordPress Text Only (Strip Out Image Tags)](http://breakthroughdesign.com/getting-the_content-wordpress-text-only-strip-out-image-tags/)" from my searches but that still uses the `get_the_content()` approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try removing (image), like this:

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: In cased images with <a> tag then content in arrived  blank <a></a> tags.

Answer (score 5):

The method I prefer to use is just a bit shorter then the previous answer.

```
<php $myExcerpt = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '' ) ; 
echo $myExcerpt ; ?>
```

The WordPress function [wp_trim_words()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/) returns only text (no images).

`wp_trim_words ( string $text, int $num_words = 55, string $more = null )`

Comment: That's not really true, wp_trim_words returns also images

Comment: This worked for me - thanks for taking the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

almost the same than derekshrink directely fom the WordPress dev.

`<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ); ?>`

you can change the number of word you want to show