# the_content() stop images being pulled through

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop

I have created a custom post type to pull through the date, title, thumbnail and content, some of the posts have images and `the_content()` is pulling through those images and I don't know how to stop it from doing this, Could someone help me with this issue?

My code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h4><?php the_date('jS F Y');?></h4>
                    <?php the_content();?>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else:?>
    <h2>There are no blog posts</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The problem is no in the code included in the question. Amost 100% sure.

Comment: The_content pull all content, I need a way to stop it pulling Images

Comment: Duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162162/how-to-remove-images-from-showing-in-a-post-with-the-content

Comment: That doesnt work for me I tried it

Comment: Sorry, I understood that `the_content()` was removing the images. So, `the_content()` prints the images in the content .... that is totally normal and the expected behaviour. The linked question by @ChrisMorris is all we can tell you. If it doesn't work, please post a sample content with images and explain how you apply the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `functions.php`

```
function mdc_remove_img($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); 
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'mdc_remove_img' );
```

Answer (score -4):

I figured out how to do this,

Instead of using `the_content();` Im now using `the_excerpt();` and Im just changing the amount of characters it brings through!

Comment: This is an awesomely bad idea.

Comment: Well It works, I dont see a problem

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of things that work but are not very clever. Read the [Developers Page about `the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) so you get at least an idea what could go wrong.