# How to remove only images from the_content()

Tags: the-content

When I call the_content(), I want to show only text and don't want to show images.
Notable that, I don't want to remove text style. The text style should be display as well.
How can I do this?

Comment: You could have probably googled this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer already here [How to remove images from showing in a post with the_content()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162162/how-to-remove-images-from-showing-in-a-post-with-the-content#162165)

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `functions.php`

```
function mdc_remove_img($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); 
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'mdc_remove_img' );
```