# Show images from TEXT section on PAGE wordpress

Tags: images

I am trying to show all images on a page in WordPress. My WordPress page is setup like you see in the image below.

[image]

What I want to do is show each of these images on a custom page I have made, called Portrait Album. See code below. I guess it is [the opposite of this that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87909/how-to-retrieve-text-only-from-wp-content-not-from-wp-excerpt) I want to implement.

I am not sure how I can show each image in the `Text` section. Does anyone out there know how to do this? Should be obvious but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

I know `get_content()` will show the content, but how can I specifically show the images, so I can show these in a loop enabling me to make a grid using CSS and create a photo gallery.

Currently this is the code I have:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Portrait Album */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="portrait-page" style="background-color: black;">
     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     echo "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $the_post->ID )."' />";
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is something like this, where `col-1-3` is one-third of the width of the page

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-3">
    echo "<img src='"RELEVANT PHP CODE HERE"' />"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% grasp what you're trying to do, but I believe using WordPress' default [Gallery shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) is what you want. When you insert an image into the content using the "Add Media" button, you can create a gallery and say how many columns you want the gallery to be.

If mark-up doesn't line-up well you could always repurpose the shortcode with your own mark-up, by using `remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );` and then coding up your own function and doing an `add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode );`